# Traceless of stress-energy tensor in $d=2$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, ward-identity

This is a question regarding Francesco, section 4.3.3. In this section, he considers the two-point function
$$
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(x) = \left< T_{\mu\nu}(x) T_{\rho\sigma}(0)\right>
$$
He then goes on to claim that symmetry of the stress-energy tensor implies $$S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(x) = S_{\nu\mu\rho\sigma}(x)~~~(1)$$
Though he doesn't mention this, I presume this is true only when $x \neq 0$ since the EM tensor is symmetric in a correlation as long as the other fields in the correlator are not evaluated at the same point.

---

EDIT: Due to some comments, I'll explain why I think so. If a theory is Poincare invariant, it has conserved currents $T^{\mu\nu}$ for translations and 
$$
j^{\mu\nu\rho} = T^{\mu\nu} x^\rho - T^{\mu\rho} x^\nu
$$
for Lorentz transformations. For completeness, we also note that if the theory has scale invariance the dilation current is 
$$
j^\mu_D = T^{\mu\nu} x_\nu
$$
In a classical theory, conservation of these currents implies symmetry and tracelessness of the stress-energy tensor. In a quantum theory, we have a Ward Identity, which for each of the currents reads
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_\mu \left< T^\mu{}_\nu X \right> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^d(x-x_i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^\nu} \left< X \right> \\
\partial_\mu \left< j^{\mu\nu\rho} X \right> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^d(x-x_i) \left( x_i^\rho\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^\nu} - x_i^\nu\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^\rho} - i S_i^{\mu\nu} \right) \left< X \right> \\
\partial_\mu \left< j^\mu_D X \right> &= - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^d(x-x_i) \left( x_i^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^\alpha} + \Delta_i \right) \left< X \right>
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $X  = \Phi_1(x_1) \cdots \Phi_n(x_n)$, $S^{\mu\nu}_i$ is the representation of the Lorentz algebra under which $\Phi_i(x_i)$ transforms and $\Delta_i$ is the scaling dimension of $\Phi_i(x_i)$. Now plugging in the exact forms of the currents $j^{\mu\nu\rho}$ and $j^\mu_D$, we find
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_\mu \left< T^\mu{}_\nu X \right> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^d(x-x_i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i^\nu} \left< X \right> \\
\left< \left( T^{\mu\nu} - T^{\nu\mu} \right) X \right> &= i \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^d(x-x_i)  S_i^{\mu\nu}   \left< X \right> \\
\left< T^\mu{}_\mu X \right> &=  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^d(x-x_i)  \Delta_i  \left< X \right>
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Clearly, the EM tensor is not symmetric under correlation functions at the points $x = x_i$.

---

Now, using these symmetry properties and certain other properties under parity, he argues that 
$$
S^\mu{}_\mu{}^\sigma{}_\sigma(x) = \left< T^\mu{}_\mu(x) T^\sigma{}_\sigma(0)\right> = 0
$$
Following the above arguments, this should then only be true at $x \neq 0$. **However, Francesco claims that this holds *everywhere* and therefore concludes that $\left< T^\mu{}_\mu(0)^2 \right> = 0$.** How does this makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, could you please write a more comprehensible explanation about why you think that any of the symmetries should break for $x=0$? The symmetry in (1) is just coming from the symmetry of the first $T_{\mu\nu}$. It's symmetric as an operator so of course all of its correlators respect the symmetry, too. There can't be any exception for $x=0$ or for Monday evenings.

Comment: $\left< T^\mu{}_\mu(0)^2 \right>$ is a scalar (relative to Lorentz transformation), translation invariant quantity (there is nothing special with the origin point, and dimensionfull quantity (in 2d it has dimension 4 in energy/mass). So if it were non vanishing, this term could be used to build a characteristic length scale and thus spoil conformal invariance. My guess...

Comment: @LubošMotl - I have added an explanation as to why I think that the statements should be valid on at $x \neq 0$. What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: @Learningisamess - I agree with you and I see why it should be true, but it doesn't seem to follow from Francesco's arguments alone (which I have outlined briefly in my question)

Comment: @Prahar : OK, I deleted my answer, but something is boring me. If we use a symmetrized Belinfante-Rosenberg tensor, which are the terms acting on the intrinsic modification of fields in this tensor ? For safety, here  is my [reference](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-7-conslaw.pdf) p.631-633

Comment: I presume you mean $\left<T_\mu{}^\mu\right> = 0$? I also thought so. For some reason, Francesco suggests that is also important to show that $\left< T^\mu{}_\mu(0)^2\right>  = 0$. Can you explain why that is?

Comment: @Prahar : No, I really meant $\langle T_\mu{}^\nu \rangle = 0$, but I am not able to prove it... Of course, if you have $\langle T_\mu{}^\mu (0)^2\rangle = 0$, it implies $\langle T_\mu{}^\mu (0)\rangle = 0$

Comment: OK. That confuses me. If $\langle T_\mu{}^\nu \rangle = 0$, isn't the theory trivial since all the charges vanish? Also, maybe I'm being dense, why should $\langle T_\mu{}^\mu(0)^2 \rangle = 0$ imply $\langle T_\mu{}^\mu(0) \rangle = 0$?

Comment: @Prahar : In fact, from $4.73$,(extended to $x=0$) ,we have automatically $S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(0) = 0$, that is,  $\langle T_{\mu\nu}(x)T_{\rho\sigma}(x)\rangle  = 0$ for all $x$...

Comment: @Prahar : The variance is always positive, and you have : $V(X) = E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 \geq 0$

Comment: @Prahar : I suppose you read the answer to my new [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76428/6316) So,  for the trace, the job is done. And you have supposed the energy tensor symmetric by hypothesis.

Comment: @Prahar : This works for flat space only.

Answer (score 3):

I think the original source of this claim is the famous unpublished paper of [Luescher and Mack](http://luscher.web.cern.ch/luscher/notes/cft2d.pdf). Everyone's citing it. It is more rigorous mathematically and general (they don't assume parity) than Di Francesco. It starts on pages 1-2 of the manuscript. The proof below is basically the same proof, just with added details and a little bit different notation.

**Assumptions:** $T_{\mu\nu}$ are local covariant fields of dimension 2 and $$T^{\dagger}_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}, \quad T_{\mu\nu} = T_{\nu\mu},\quad \partial^{\mu}T_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$ Moreover, one assumes that the correlation functions are well-defined and behaved, and satisfy usual axioms of CFT as stated e.g. [in this page of nLab](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/conformal+field+theory#2d_cft_on_the_plane).

**Proof:**
First we define the 2-point functions
    $$
 S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) := \text{analytic continuation of } \langle \Omega \mid T_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}) T_{\rho\sigma}(\vec{y}) \mid \Omega \rangle.
 $$
All $S$'s are translationally invariant, so we may as well set $\vec{y}=0$
so that we are left with
$$
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x}) := \langle \Omega \mid T_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}) T_{\rho\sigma}(0) \mid \Omega \rangle.
$$
This function is real analytic for $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2,\, \vec{x}\neq 0$, and because of invariance under dilations, and the assumption that $T_{\mu\nu}$'s are of conformal weight 2, we have

\begin{equation}
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=\lambda^4 S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\lambda \vec{x})\quad\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}.\quad\quad (1)
\end{equation}
Moreover, from $T_{\mu\nu}=T_{\nu\mu}$ we get
$$
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=S_{\nu\mu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=S_{\mu\nu\sigma\rho}(\vec{x}).\quad\quad (2)
$$
Furthermore, by locality, invariance under translations and Equation 1 with $\lambda=-1$ we get
$$
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x},0)=S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(0,\vec{x})=S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(-\vec{x},0)=S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(\vec{x},0),
$$
or in shorthand notation 
$$
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x}) = S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(\vec{x}) .\quad\quad (3)
$$
From Equations 2 and 3 we see that $S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})$ has 6 independent components and also taking into account Equation 1 we can write
$$
S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x}) = (\vec{x}^{\,2})^{-4}\sum_{i=1}^6 \alpha_i f^{\,i} _{\mu\nu\sigma\rho}(\vec{x}),\quad \alpha_i\in\mathbb{C},\quad\quad (4)
$$
where
\begin{align} 
&f^{1}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=(\vec{x}^{\,2})^2 g_{\mu\nu} g_{\rho\sigma},\\\\ &f^{2}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=(\vec{x}^{\,2})^2 (g_{\mu\rho} g_{\nu\sigma}+g_{\mu\sigma}g_{\nu\rho}),\\\\ &f^{3}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=\vec{x}^{\,2} (g_{\mu\nu} x_\rho x_\sigma + g_{\rho\sigma} x_\mu x_\nu ),\\\\ &f^{4}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})=x_\mu x_\nu x_\rho x_\sigma,\\\\ &f^{5}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})= \vec{x}^{\,2} \left (g_{\mu\nu} (x_\rho \varepsilon_{\sigma\delta}x^\delta+x_\sigma\varepsilon_{\rho\delta}x^\delta )+ g_{\rho\sigma} (x_\mu\varepsilon_{\nu\delta} x^\delta + x_\nu \varepsilon_{\mu\delta}x^\delta) \right),\\\\ &f^{6}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x})= \left( x_\mu \varepsilon_{\nu\delta}x^\delta +x_\nu \varepsilon_{\mu\delta}x^\delta \right) x_\rho x_\sigma + x_\mu x_\nu \left( x_\rho \varepsilon_{\sigma\delta}x^\delta + x_\sigma \varepsilon_{\rho\delta}x^\delta \right),
\end{align}
and
$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{\mu\nu},\quad \varepsilon_{\mu\nu}=-\varepsilon_{\nu\mu},\quad \varepsilon_{01}=+1,\quad \vec{x}^{\,2}=(x^0)^2+(x^1)^2.
$$
The continuity equation $\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0$ implies that $\partial^\mu S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}(\vec{x}) = 0$ and thus reduces the number of independent $\alpha_i$'s to 2 arbitrary constants $\alpha_+$ and $\alpha_-$ *(checked myself using Mathematica)*:
\begin{alignat*}{6}
&\alpha_1 = 3 \alpha_+,\quad         &&\alpha_2 = -\alpha_+,\quad \alpha_3 = -4\alpha_+,\quad \alpha_4 = 8\alpha_+,&\\
&\alpha_5 = \alpha_-,\quad             &&\alpha_6 = -2\alpha_-.             &
\end{alignat*}
Inserting these values into Equation 4 we obtain:
$$
S^{\mu}_{\;\mu\rho\sigma} (\vec{x}) = S^{\mu\;\rho}_{\;\mu\;\rho} (\vec{x}) = 0,
$$
i.e. $\langle\Omega \mid T^\mu_{\;\mu}(\vec{x})\, T^\rho_{\;\rho} (0)\mid\Omega\rangle = 0$, which by the **Reeh-Schlieder Theorem** implies that $T^\mu_{\;\mu}(\vec{x})=0$.

Now to be able to apply Reeh-Schlieder, we actually have to go to $\vec{x}=0$ as you have correctly pointed out. And the reason why we can do this is analytic continuation, citing p 110 of R. JOST: The General Theory of Quantized Fields, 1965 (the same step in a related lemma):

**"Such a Wigtman distribution thus vanishes in the real regularity points and thus, by analytic continuation identically".**

**tl;dr analytic continuation**